# Copy value from other table on insert trigger, postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm quite new to PostgreSQL and have spend too much time already to try to find an example to adapt for what i want to do. So I hope I can get some help here

I have 2 tables, call them person and address

I want to create a trigger that copy street and house_nr from table Address when I insert a new value for person_id in the first table where person_id = oid

> Table person
>   person_id
>   street
>   house_nr
>   other_attributes
>
> Table Address
>   oid
>   street
>   house_nr
>   other_attributes

Something like this

```
INSERT INTO person
set person.street = address.street,
    person.house_nr = address.house_nr
FROM address
WHERE person_id = oid
```

Hope someone will have time to help
cheers

Comment: What you ask is possible. However I do not get why you are asking for it. It is redundant to have the same data in two places, since you can access address data.

Comment: Yes it does look redundant with the simple example of columns I have here. I will use it in an application where the user will type in the id and the other fields will be filled in automatically. The "master table" is generated with a view over several tables.

Comment: Another situation where this is useful is when the associated data can change over time, but the current table is historical record and should remain static.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First you need to create a trigger function. (Detailed info on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_before_trigger_on_person()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    SELECT address.street, address.house_nr
        INTO NEW.street, NEW.house_nr
    FROM address
    WHERE address.oid = NEW.person_id;

    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Then you need to add this function to the table. (Detailed info on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_trigger_on_person
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON person
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_before_trigger_on_person();
```

I did not try this specific solution. However it should work, I just modified my own triggers on Postgres 9.3

Comment: Thank you!! I will go ahead and try it out

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. It gave me more insight to how write triggers too.
Very much appreciated!!